# Kernel and image of a product of two rectangular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I cannot find any concise and effective answer to the following problem :

**Problem :** given two matrices $A$ and $B$ of size $3\times 2$ and $2\times 3$ such that $AB = \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1\\ 1  & 1 & 2 \end{matrix}\right)$ find the kernel and the image of $AB$ and $BA$.

**What I have found so far :** Ker$(AB)=$ Vect$\left(\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} \right)$ and Im$(AB) = $ Vect$\left(\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \right)$. Furthermore $AB \in S_3(\mathbb{R})$ so AB is diagonalizable, and I have $\chi_{AB}=X(X+1)(X-3)$ so :

$\mathrm{Sp}(AB) = \{-1,0,3 \}$ and $E_{-1}(AB) = \mathrm{Vect}\left( \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \right) \quad E_{0}(AB) = \mathrm{Vect}\left( \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} \right) \quad E_{3}(AB) = \mathrm{Vect}\left( \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} \right) $

Then I had the idea of saying if $X$ is an eigenvector of $AB$ then there exists $\lambda \in \{-1,0,3\}$ such as $ABX = \lambda X$ so $BABX = \lambda BX$ and thus $BX$ is either null or an eigenvector of $BA$ for the eigenvalue $\lambda$. Furthermore $BA$ is a square matrix of size 2 so $BA$ cannot have $3$ distinct eigenvalues, it has at most $2$ eigenvalues that can be found within $\{-1,0,3\}$.

I have stopped here. **I don't expect any complete answer**, just any idea will be welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that rank($AB$) $=2$

This implies $A$ and $B$ are full rank, i.e. $B$ is surjective and $A$ is injective.

Since $A$ is injective, Ker $(AB) = $ Ker $B$

Since $B$ is surjective, Im $(AB) = $ Im $A$

Since   $\left(\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} \right)$ are linearly independent, we see that

Ker $B$ $\cap$ Im $A =$ Ker $AB$ $\cap$ Im $AB = 0$

Thus,

Ker $BA = $ Ker $A = 0$ so that $BA$ is invertible since it is square

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer. Should the third vector be (1 1 -1) (typo)?

Comment: That is a nice approach. So what do you suggest for $\mathrm{Im}(BA)$ then?

Comment: Ok I got it, as $BA$ is invertible so $BA$ is bijective (isomorphism) and as $((1 \; 0),(0 \; 1))$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ then $\mathrm{Im}(BA) = (BA(1 \; 0), BA(0 \; 1))$

Comment: Do you think we can do something knowing $(AB)^2$ and that $AB$ is diagonalizable though?

Comment: Could you explain simply how you can prove "This implies A and B are full rank, i.e. B is surjective and A is injective.", I could see why it works, but do you have any more rigourous explanation please? I will validate your answer afterwards.

Comment: Corrected that typo (thanks). We're just using that Rank(AB) <= min{Rank(A), Rank(B)}. Since $B$ has rank two, it's columns span $\mathbb R^2$, since $A$ has rank two, its two columns are LI, so that it is injective.

Comment: Since $BA$ is square and has 0 kernel, it's image is  $\mathbb R^2$  (you can use the dimension formula to show this).