# Kernel and image of a product of two rectangular matrices (another method)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I wanted to share another approach on my previous question :
[Kernel and image of a product of two rectangular matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3645632/kernel-and-image-of-a-product-of-two-rectangular-matrices)

**The problem was** : given two matrices $A$ and $B$ of size $3\times 2$ and $2\times 3$ such that $AB = \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1\\ 1  & 1 & 2 \end{matrix}\right)$ find the kernel and the image of $AB$ and $BA$.

Coriolanus's answer was great but maybe a bit too general for this specific case. So here is an another method, I have rewritten it from the beginning.

*Feel free to correct me, for english is not my mother tongue.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First let's determine $\mathrm{Ker}(AB)$ and $\mathrm{Im}(AB)$** :

$X =\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix} \in \mathrm{Ker}(AB) \Leftrightarrow AB X = 0 \Leftrightarrow \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1\\ 1  & 1 & 2 \end{matrix}\right) \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix} = 0 \Leftrightarrow  \left\{\begin{array}{l} y+z=0 \\ x+z=0 \\ x+y+2z=0 \end{array}  \right. \hspace{4cm}\stackrel{L_3 = L_1+L_2}{\Leftrightarrow} \left\{\begin{array}{l} y+z=0 \\ x+z=0  \end{array} \right. \Leftrightarrow X = x \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$

Therefore $\boxed{\mathrm{Ker}(AB)= \mathrm{Vect}\left( \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} \right)}$.

For $X = \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^3$, $ABX = \begin{pmatrix} y+z \\ x+z \\ x+y+2z \end{pmatrix} = x \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} + y\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} +z \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$.

So $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ are in $\mathrm{Im}(AB)$ and are linearly independant. By the rank theorem : $$\mathrm{rank}(AB) = 3-\mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{Ker}(AB)) = 3-1 =2$$

So $\left(\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}\right)$ is a linearly independant sequence of two vectors in a vector space of dimension 2. Thus,

$$\boxed{ \mathrm{Im}(AB) = \mathrm{Vect}\left(\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \right)}. $$

**Then let's find the eigenvalues of $AB$ :**

Notice that $AB$ is diagonalizable according to the spectral theorem because it belongs to $S_3(\mathbb{R})$. Let's calculate $\chi_{AB}$ the characteristic polynomial of $AB$ to have access to the eigenvalues :

$\chi_{AB} = \det(XI_3-AB) = \begin{vmatrix} X &-1 &-1 \\ -1 & X & -1 \\ -1 & -1 & X-2 \end{vmatrix} \stackrel{C_1 \leftarrow C_1 - C_2}{=} \begin{vmatrix} X+1 &-1 &-1 \\ -X-1 & X & -1 \\ 0 & -1 & X-2 \end{vmatrix}$

$\; \; \stackrel{L_2 \leftarrow L_2 +L_1}{=}(X+1) \begin{vmatrix} 1 &-1 &-1 \\ 0 & X-1 & -2 \\ 0 & -1 & X-2 \end{vmatrix} {=}(X+1)1(-1)^{1+1} \begin{vmatrix} X-1 & -2 \\ -1 & X-2 \end{vmatrix}$

$\; \; \stackrel{C_1 \rightarrow C_1 + C_2}{=}(X+1) \begin{vmatrix} X-3 & -2 \\ X-3 & X-2\end{vmatrix} =(X+1)(X-3) \begin{vmatrix} 1 & -2 \\ 1 & X-2\end{vmatrix} =(X+1)(X-3)(X-2+2) $

$\hspace{0.9cm} = X(X+1)(X-3) $

Therefore $\mathrm{Sp}(AB) = \{0,-1,3\}$ (the roots of $\chi_{AB}$).

**Finally, let's determine $\mathrm{Ker}(BA)$ and $\mathrm{Im}(BA)$ :**

As $AB \in S_3(\mathbb{R})$, there exists a basis $(e_{0},e_{-1},e_3)$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$  where $e_0,e_{-1},e_3$ are eigenvectors of $AB$ for respective eigenvalues $0,-1$ and $3$ (by the spectral theorem).

Consequently, $AB e_{-1} = -e_{-1}$ and $Be_{-1} \neq 0$ (otherwise we would have $-e_{-1} = 0$ and that would contradict the fact that $e_{-1}$ is an eigenvector) so $BABe_{-1} = -Be_{-1}$. Therefore $Be_{-1} \neq 0$ is an eigenvector of $BA$ for eigenvalue $-1$.

Likewise $Be_3$ is an eigenvector of $BA$ for eigenvalue $3$.

So $(Be_{-1},Be_3)$ is a sequence (of two eigenvectors for two distinct eigenvalues) in
$\mathbb{R}^2$ ($B$ has 2 lines) that is linearly independant, so it is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Therefore : $$\mathrm{Im}(BA) = \mathrm{Vect}(BABe_{-1},BABe_{3}) =\mathrm{Vect}(-Be_{-1},3Be_{3}) = \mathrm{Vect}(Be_{-1},Be_{3}) =\mathbb{R}^2 $$

Finally, as $BA$ is a square matrix of size 2, by the rank theorem :

$$\mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{Ker}(BA)) = 2-\mathrm{rank}(BA) = 2-2= 0 $$

As a conclusion : $$\boxed{\mathrm{Ker}(BA) = \{0\} }\quad \quad \boxed{\mathrm{Im}(BA) = \mathbb{R}^2}$$

Comment: It’s a solid effort, but it seems like way too much work compared to the original answer that you cited.

Comment: Thank you @amd. Yes maybe it is slighty too much, but the original answer was using results that need (at my level) to be proven (even if it is not hard) and it takes work too. The original exercise was more focused on diagonalization, so I thought I needed to find out an other solution.